# Cloud Storage triggered Cloud Function always timed out and exceeds deadline

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am using **Google Cloud Storage events** to trigger a cloud function that writes an uploaded CSV into Cloud Datastore. Problem is the csv files have more than `8000 rows` and the function's maximum timeout of `9mins` is not enough.

```
Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded
```

I also tried batch operations but it's still the same timeout problem. **Is there an alternative solution I can use where there is not much re-architecturing involved?**

```
const {Datastore} = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const db = new Datastore();
const storage = new Storage();

const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');

exports.updateMasterlist = async (object, context, callback) => {

    const fileBucket = object.bucket;
    const filePath = object.name; 
    const bucket = storage.bucket(fileBucket);
    const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);

    await bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath})
    
    var total = 0; 
    var max = 0;
    var employees = [];
    var batch = 1;
    const kind = 'masterlist';

    fs.createReadStream(tempFilePath)
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (record) => {
            let key = record['EmployeeID'];
            var empKey = db.key([kind, key]);

            const employee = {
                emp_id: record['EmployeeID'],
                full_name: `${record['Firstname']} ${record['MiddleName']} ${record['Lastname']}`,
                group: record['GroupName'],
                division: record['Division'],
                department: record['Department'],
                is_id: record['SupervisorID'],
                email_address: record['Email']
            };

            const emp_entity = {
                key: empKey,
                data: employee,
            };

            employees.push(emp_entity);
            total++; max++;

            if (max >= 499){
                try {
                    db.upsert(employees);
                    console.log(`Uploading batch ${batch}`);
                    batch++;
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                    process.exit(1);
                }
                employees.length = 0;
                max=0; 
            }

        })
        .on('end', async () => {
            try {
                await db.upsert(employees);
                console.log(`Uploading batch ${batch}`);
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
                process.exit(1);
            }
            console.log("End of CSV file read!");
            console.log(`BATCH INFORMATION: `);
            console.log(`number of employees: ${total}`);
        });

    callback();
};
```

Comment: Could you provide some code, please. It's suspicious to me that it takes that long. Even 8000 rows shouldn't take too long - what's the size of the csv? Is there multiple?

Comment: You might be doing something wrong in your code, please edit the question to share  it.

Comment: Edit: I have added the code

Comment: My first impression is that you're not dealing with promises correctly.

Comment: How long does it take for the function to write 8000 rows to your on-premises environment?

Comment: @J.A.Hernández this funtion is initially written for Datastore. so I can't tell

Comment: How big is your CSV file?

Comment: @J.A.Hernández it's 1.59 MB

Comment: I rechecked your code and how it was mentioned above in the comments, this could be due to an issue in the promises, to know if this process is too long for  a cloud function , please try to run the function in your environment local, if the process never ends, this could be related to the code flow; otherwise, please share how long this process takes in the local environment.

Comment: @J.A.Hernández yeah. the Promises seem to be the problem. I'm a novice in using them at the moment. I was able to do the function in Python and it is working. Not sure if I should use that to answer this thread

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Python 3.7

```
from google.cloud import datastore
import csv
import time
start_time = time.time()
db = datastore.Client()
employees = []
count=1

with open('masterlist.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for record in reader:
        # Datastore Entities
        key = record['EmployeeID']
        empKey = db.key('masterlist', key)
        employee = datastore.Entity(key=empKey)

        employee.update({
            'emp_id': record['EmployeeID'],
            'full_name': str(record['Firstname']+' '+record['MiddleName']+' '+record['Lastname']),
            'group': record['GroupName'],
            'division': record['Division'],
            'department': record['Department'],
            'is_id': record['SupervisorID'],
            'email_address': record['Email']
        })
        employees.append(employee)

        if(len(employees) >= 499):
            db.put_multi(employees)
            employees.clear()
            print('Batch: '+str(count)+' added')
            count += 1

db.put_multi(employees)
print('Batch: '+str(count)+' added')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```